# uniform boundedness can be relaxed to pointwise boundedness in Arzela ascoli theorem?

Tags: arzela-ascoli

Let $C(X)$ be the space of continuous functions with the usual norm. $X$ be a compact metric space. The Arzela Ascolis theorem says:

A subset $S$ of $C(X)$ is compact iff it is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous at any point of $x$.

I think the uniform boundedness can be relaxed to that $S$ is bounded at any point $x$.

Is that actually true or are there prominent counter examples?

Comment: If you relax it to pointwise bounded then you get precompactness instead of compactness

Comment: I see thank you!

Comment: @Lorago are you sure? I think if we not assume $F$ to be closed, we get always just precompactness, no? And uniform boundedness is just unecessary I think because picking a subsequence we only need boundedness of the whole set for any $t$.

Comment: You can check the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem) page on it, where one of the statements is "Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Then a subset $F$ of $C(X)$ is relatively compact in the topology induced by the uniform norm if and only if it is equicontinuous and pointwise bounded."